# Get status of form submission from backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Is it possible to get status of each steps from backend? Like when I submit multipart form through ajax, it should show file upload progress, once it's finished it should show file format conversion progress then aws upload progress. Tried following ajax trick but it only show for upload progress.

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type:"POST",
        data: data,
        processData: false, 
        contentType: false,
        xhr: function(){
            var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr() ;
            // set the onprogress event handler
            xhr.upload.onprogress = function(evt){ console.log('progress', evt.loaded/evt.total*100) } ;
            // set the onload event handler
            xhr.upload.onload = function(){ console.log('DONE!') } ;
            // return the customized object
            return xhr ;
        }

    })
```

it's expressjs in backend. Please let me know if I'm doing it wrong or any suggestions.

Comment: You need to make your backend report progress.  You should probably use Socket.io.

Comment: is there any way to get progress status of entire form submit until ajax done function is called? like i wan't to show wha't going in backend i'e. converting file, moving to aws, saving to database .. any idea?

Comment: There is no native way to do that, because there is no notion of any of those concepts as formally existing.  You need to report progress in your own code.